# Is there a time limit for any question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post *[Printing a Message Entered By User Multiple Times (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829087/printing-a-message-entered-by-user-multiple-times-android-studio)*.

Can I mention anybody in the body of the question so he/she can answer?

Also, if I need to discuss the question more after a long time, should I open a new one and refer to it or just reply to the same question. (I.e., is there a time limit for any question?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can I mention anybody in the body of the question so he can answer?

You can, but there's no guarantee that they see it so there's little point in doing so.

If you tag your question correctly then the people following those tags will see it and answer if they feel they are able.

> also, if I need to discuss the question more after a long time, should I open a new one and refer to it or just reply to the same question. (i.e. is there a time limit for any question?)

No, don't ask a new question. Update your existing question with any additional information that you've discovered - as long as it's relevant and doesn't invalidate any existing answers. There's no time limit on questions. They remain open (assuming that they are good quality questions) for ever.

Comment: Should note that if you do open a new question asking the same thing one of the questions is liable to be closed as a "duplicate", and both are liable to attract the kind of attention that your *don't* want; i.e. downvotes

Answer (score 4):

> Can I mention anybody in the body of the question so he/she can answer?

Just on this point.

I would advise NOT to do that.  People are liable to interpret that as a "bugging" them.  If people do that to me, I am often inclined to be irritated with them.

Questions here are answered by volunteers in their spare time.  You should respect that.  Just 'cos someone has helped you before, or you *think* that they can help you, doesn't mean that it is OK to "tap them on the shoulder".